# Laravel 5.5 controller sending variables to ReactJS component

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5.5

I have a site already developed in Laravel 5.5 and trying to implement React preset in it, but I want to send the variables I use in Blade to the React components to do the rendering.

I installed laracasts/utilities and followed the instructions here https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer changing the namespace to `reactBinding` but it isn't working as expected.

On Laravel I do:

```
JavaScript::put([
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'age' => 29
]);
```

When running `console.log(window)` I can see it has the spacename I created with the corresponding values, but `console.log(window.reactBinding)` and `console.log(reactBinding)` are both undefined.

Any idea what I could be missing? Is there any extra step to make it work in React? Is there a better way to send variables from Laravel controllers to React components?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

I was including the JS codes in the wrong order. As logic indicates, the view used to prepend the code from `PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer` must be place **before** the `app.js` inclusion.

My bad!